# Split values using drag and drop

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

```
textbox1.text = 123 ;
textbox2.text = examples ;
```

i added to listbox above two textbox values in `listbox1`

after adding like show in `listbox = 123 examples`

```
    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
        DataGridViewCell targetCell = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex];

        if (targetCell.Value == null)
        {
            targetCell.Value = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            if (targetCell.Value.ToString().Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Split(' ')[1]))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                targetCell.Value = targetCell.Value.ToString().Split(' ')[1] + System.Environment.NewLine + e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

            }
        }

        textBox3.Text = e.Data.GetData("System.String").ToString().Split()[0];
    }
```

now if i drag and drop to my datagridview any cell from my listbox item (123 examples),it should be split like,textbox3.text = 123; and examples to datagridview cell.

above code using but its split but not solved.

**Visual Example:**

[image]

Comment: The way you add the "texts" to your textboxes won't work. You need to put them in quotationmarks, e.g. `textbox2.text = "examples";`

Comment: yes i already put quotes but after drag and drop give us problem.

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: the output is "123" is in textbox3 and "123 sometext" is in datagridview cell,means 123 is repeated in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, your logic is wrong.

Just replace this code snippet

```
if (targetCell.Value == null)
{
    targetCell.Value = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
}
else
{
    if (targetCell.Value.ToString().Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Split(' ')[1]))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        targetCell.Value = targetCell.Value.ToString().Split(' ')[1] + System.Environment.NewLine + e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

    }
}
```

with this line:

```
targetCell.Value = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Split(' ')[1];
```

---

**For dynamic selection of "TextBoxes:"**

Create a global array of **TextBoxes** and initialize it in your form's constructor:

```
TextBox[] arrTextBox;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //initializing the array
    arrTextBox = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
}
```

Now use it like:

```
//get RowIndex of selected Cell and get the same index TextBox from the array
arrTextBox[targetCell.RowIndex].Text = e.Data.GetData("System.String").ToString().Split()[0];
```

---

**Complete Code:**

```
TextBox[] arrTextBox;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //initializing the array
    arrTextBox = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
}

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
    DataGridViewCell targetCell = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex];

    targetCell.Value = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Split(' ')[1];   //for GridCell

    arrTextBox[targetCell.RowIndex].Text = e.Data.GetData("System.String").ToString().Split()[0];   //for TextBox
}
```

Comment: Whats the result now?

Comment: same as above,123 is in textbox3 and 123 example in datagrid view cell

Comment: What is the initial value of the cell (before dropping the listItem)?

Comment: Your scenario is still not very clear to me. Can you show a visual example?

Comment: how to add my visual file.am not able to upload the rar file.suggest me steps.

Comment: @Varta Upload it somewhere else and give link into the question.

Comment: this is my link for visual file http://www.mediafire.com/download/sien8biv9g84aru/WindowsFormsApplication1.rar

Comment: This is not a good idea to send complete code. You must update your question with all the details. I've done it for you. Check the updated answer as well.

Comment: thankyou Shaharyar,its ok but problem is if i select another item from listbox and drop to next cell ,then it should be not spilitted to 2nd textbox.i need textbox1 with 1st colomn row[0],textbox2 with row[1],textbox3 with row[2] and textbox4 with row[3].

Comment: I was thinking for exactly the same. You can manually check for it, `if(rowIndex == 1) textbox1.Text = .....`. But I will suggest you to create an array of textboxes.

Comment: plz littile help me dear Shaharyar

Comment: Check out the updated answer. I've used an array for dynamic textbox selection

Comment: ,i have face one more problem.if i drag and drop datagridview cell to another cell not working.

Comment: Because the data you handled in your code is `string` type.